# Multilevel modeling sample size

Tags: regression, sample-size, multilevel-analysis

I have a question regarding multilevel modeling. I am building a 3-level model: 1st level yearly observations (variables which vary between years), 2nd level variables on company level, which do not vary between years, 3rd level industries, 4th level country based variables. The problem is that I have only one country, and here is my question: Is it ok if I use country variables on the 3rd level besides industry variables? or is it better to just skip country variables? If I use country variables at 4th level, there is a problem as I have only one country (one group), which would lead to inaccurate estimates of regression coefficients.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If you have only 1 country then your country variables do not vary within that country, right ? Otherwise they would not be country-level variables. As such, there is no point including them in any way.

Comment: Yes you are correct, they are the same for all units included in research. but I would like to see if they have any influence on dependent variable (also compared to variables on other levels). For example if GDP has any influence on indebtedness of the company, even though if it is the same for all companies.  Does it make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment, I understand that country variables such as GDP, while they are constant for each company, vary from year to year. Since year is the lowest level (level 1) in your data hierarchy, you can include these as level 1 variables. There is no need to add an additional (4th) level of nesting, at least in software that I use (such as `lme4` in R).

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the answer, will try that. Have a nice day.